# Remove specific string from Shared Preference's key

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences

I am storing comma-separated value in Shared preferences key. I want to remove specific string from my key. How to remove the string-value from shared preferences.

Comment: try reading the key,val, edit the val and store it again...

Comment: @Xoce Thanks very helpful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open the pref.**

```
SharedPreferences myAppPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
String myTextToEdit = myAppPreferences.getString("prefKey", "");
```

---

**modify/repalce the entry:**

```
myTextToEdit = "?????";
```

---

**store it back in the pref.**

```
Editor edit = myAppPreferences.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.putString("prefKey", myTextToEdit));
edit.commit();
```